# How to pass asp.net value to javascript function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCentersList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          DataKeyNames="CenterID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="gv-classic">
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="GridCheckBox" runat="server" onclick="javascript:func1150(this,<%#response.write(CenterID)%>);" />
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CenterID" HeaderText="CenterID" SortExpression="CenterID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CenterName" HeaderText="CenterName" SortExpression="CenterName" />                                            
 </Columns></asp:GridView><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CityName ASC) AS ROWID, * FROM [CentersList]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my question in this line

```
onclick="javascript:func1150(this,<%=CenterID%>);"
```

how can I pass the CenterID to the func1150 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox 
    ID="GridCheckBox" 
    runat="server" 
    onclick='<%# string.Format("javascript:func1150(this, \"{0}\")", Eval("CenterID")) %>' 
/>
```

But do you really need a server side checkbox here? If not this could be more readable:

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    onclick="javascript:func1150(this, '<%# Eval("CenterID") %>');" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question,

```
onclick=javascript:func1150(this,'<%# Eval("CenterID")%>');
```

A better way would be adding the onclick attribute from code behind.

Comment: Centerid will unfortunately not be the id of the tag. You'd need to go through clientid of the grid to aquire the generated id of the html tag